# Java Substring conditional end

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a strings such as:

```
String test1 = "https://31.191.110.125:443/App/ws/list/play";
String test2 = "https://31.191.110.125:443/App/ws/list";
```

I want the substring output for both the above strings to be `/ws/list`

From `/ws/` to first `/` or end of string if there is no `/`

```
String sub = test1.substring(test1.indexOf("/ws/"), test1.lastIndexOf("/"));
System.out.println("Substring: " + sub);
```

The above works for test1 string, but not for test2 string. 
How can I do this for test2 string?

Comment: What is the rule here? Everything from `/ws` to where?

Comment: @Sweeper from /ws to first / or end of string if there is no /

Comment: But in the second string there is a `/` after `/ws`, so the output for the second string should be `/ws/` right? Or do you mean to the first `/` after `/ws/`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, you are right in your second part, I've edited the question

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex:

```
/ws/.*?(?=/|$)
```

like this

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/ws/.*?(?=/|$)").matcher("https://31.191.110.125:443/App/ws/list");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("There is no /ws/");
}
```

It first finds `/ws/`, then matches every character lazily until it finds either the end of the string or a `/`.

You can see a more detailed explanation of the regex and test out more strings [here](https://regex101.com/r/V6XdmH/1).

Edit:

As Andy Turner suggested, `/ws/[^/]*` is another regex you could use, and is also faster. It first finds `/ws/` then matches 0 or more non-`/` characters, as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the equivalent of [Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862581/3788176) without regex, should you so desire:

```
int start = test1.indexOf("/ws/");
if (start >= 0) {
  int end = test1.indexOf("/", start + "/ws/".length());
  String found = end >= 0 ? test1.substring(start, end) : test1.substring(start);
  // ...
}
```

This will likely be faster than a regex-based approach, because it doesn't have to compile the regex. Of course, that comes at the cost of increased verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

You could isolate the indexes then use a ternary operator, e.g :

```
int idx1 = test1.indexOf("/ws");

int idx2 = test1.lastIndexOf("/");

String sub = test1.substring(idx1, idx2 > idx1 ? idx2 : test1.length());
```

Comment: This should probably take into account that `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` *may* return `-1`

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your second String `lastIndexOf` `/` is same as for `/ws`, so you can achieve it by using a simple `if` statement i.e if they are same then last index should be length of `String`

```
String test1 = "https://31.191.110.125:443/App/ws/list/play";
String test2 = "https://31.191.110.125:443/App/ws/list";

int firstIndex = test2.indexOf("/ws");
int lastIndex = test2.lastIndexOf("/");
if(firstIndex == lastIndex){
    lastIndex = test2.length();
}
String sub = test1.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex);
System.out.println("Substring: " + sub);
```